# Angular: Binding messages from Pubnub

Tags: angular, pubnub

I'm using PubNubAngular to receive messages from Server. I received messages successfully but my binding in Angular is not working.

Here's my function:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PubNubAngular } from 'pubnub-angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [PubNubAngular]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'GDentalv2';
  private publishkey = '';
  private subscribekey = '';
  public msg: string = "";


  constructor(public pubnub: PubNubAngular) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pubnubInit();
  }

  pubnubInit() {

    this.pubnub.init({
      publishKey: this.publishkey,
      subscribeKey: this.subscribekey,
      ssl: true,
      uuid: "client"
    });
    this.pubnub.addListener({
      status: function (st) {
        if (st.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
          // this.pubnub.publish({
          //   message: 'Hello from the PubNub Angular2 SDK!',
          //   channel: 'pubnub_onboarding_channel'
          // });
        }
      },
      message: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        this.msg= message.message.content;
        console.log(this.msg);
      }
    });

    this.pubnub.subscribe({
      channels: ['pubnub_onboarding_channel'],
      withPresence: true,
      triggerEvents: ['message', 'presence', 'status']
    });
  }
}
```

In my `app.component.html`:

```html
<p>{{ msg }}</p>
```

After receiving the message, the variable `msg` remains unchanged in `app.component.html`. I don't understand why that is.

Please help me!

Comment: Can you provide the PubNub SDK version you are using and what is the link that has the code you are following?

Comment: Can you post all the component code please?

Comment: What Raz said ^^^. I think we need more context. See this link for more details: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angularjs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

Comment: Does this component or **one of its ancestors** are implementing OnPush strategy?

Comment: Sorry I'm late, I have just updated my component.ts. That's all my components and I followed the docs https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angular2-javascript/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with function scope. Change from standard functions to arrow function in your listener.

You have

```
    this.pubnub.addListener({
      ...
      message: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        this.msg= message.message.content;
        console.log(this.msg);
      }
    });
```

Change it to use arrow functions to fix scope of ***this*** keyword

```
    this.pubnub.addListener({
      ...
      message: (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        this.msg= message.message.content;
        console.log(this.msg);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!, it's work ^^, but i still don't understand this